# Possible lock combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

A combination look has 60 different position. To open the look you need to move to 3 numbers. If consecutive numbers cannot be the same, how many different combinations are there?

I am not sure if the possible position can have 60 options or 59 because consecutive options cannot be the same.

Comment: What have you done so far? What about the simpler case where a lock has 3 different positions? Try and solve it for some small cases and see how you would extend it to your problem.

Comment: My confusion lies with the 1st position. I don't know if it should be 60 or 59. It would be 59 if I take into consideration that the second position is next to the first. It could be 60 if I am to ignore al the numbers selected after the first.

Comment: How many choices do you have for your first position, keeping in mind that you haven't chosen any other numbers yet? There are no restrictions at that point.

Comment: Technically 60, but the second position is next to the first but occurs later in time, so do I consider the choice I will make on the second position while making the first.

Comment: When you are choosing the first you haven't chosen a second, so you have nothing to consider. Basically you can only look backwards in time at previous choices.

Comment: The problem is not well worded. Early on it says the three numbers are different. Then it says that two consecutives cannot be the same. That's automatically taken care of if the numbers are different. So question, is 25-17-25 allowed?

Comment: Yes, only consecutive numbers have to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address your question in the case of a combination lock with 5 positions and the same restriction. First, how many choices do you have for the first position? At that point, no other numbers have been chosen so you don't need to worry about what a previous choice had been. Therefore you have 5 possible first positions. Once you've chosen your first position, you only have 4 options remaining for your second, since you can't repeat your previous choice. For your third position, you can't repeat your second position, but you can go back to your first, so you still have 4 options available. Therefore the total number of combinations is $5\cdot 4\cdot 4=80.$ How does this generalize to 60 possible positions?